# Append Collections together

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections, both have a structure like this:

```
id    trips_in
1     5
2     10

id    trips_out
1     6
2     8
```

My question is how can I combine them into a single collection like such:

```
id    trips_in    trips_out
1     5           6
2     10          8
```

I found out about `mapReduce`, but its functionality looks like more than what I need. I wrote the following query:

```
tripsInMap = function() {
    var values = {
        trips_in: this.trips_in
    };
    emit(this._id, values);
};
tripsOutMap = function() {
    var values = {
        trips_out: this.trips_out
    };
    emit(this._id, values);
};
reduce = function(key, values) {
  var result = {
      "trips_out" : "",
      "trips_in" : ""
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      if(value.trips_out !== null) {result.trips_out = value.trips_out;}

      if(value.trips_in !== null) {result.trips_in = value.trips_in;}
    });

    return result;
}
db.tripsIn.mapReduce(tripsInMap, reduce, {"out": {"reduce": "joined"}});
db.tripsOut.mapReduce(tripsOutMap, reduce, {"out": {"reduce": "joined"}});
```

However I end up with `"trips_in": undefined`. I wonder if there is a better method.

Comment: can you add a query , you can update the query to acheive this . also , here is the link to do the same  ** https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-array **

Comment: @anoop I added my query. I don't see how that package is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be the fastest way, you could try something like this:

```
// Create the new collection with data from the tripsIn collection
db.tripsIn.find().forEach( function(trip) { 
    db.tripsJoined.insert({ _id: trip._id, trips_in: trip.trips_in, trips_out: 0 }); 
})

// Update the trips_out field in the tripsJoined collection
// using upsert:true to insert records that are not found
db.tripsOut.find().forEach( function(trip) {
    db.tripsJoined.update(
        { _id: trip._id}, 
        {$inc: {trips_in: 0, trips_out: trip.trips_out}}, 
        {upsert: true});
})
```

The first line will iterate through each document in the `tripsIn` collection and insert a corresponding document in the `tripsJoined` collection with the `trips_out` field set.

The second line will iterate over the `tripsOut` collection, and for each document it will update the corresponding `tripsJoined` document with the `trips_out` value.

Note that I added `{$inc: {trips_in: 0`... and `upsert:true`. This was done so that if any documents of trips exist in the `tripsOut` collection that do not have a corresponding _id value in the `tripsIn` collection, the document is inserted and the `trips_in` field is initialized to 0.